# Failed to load the "vagrant-azure" plugin

Tags: azure, vagrant

I've been following this vagrant azure tutorial     https://unindented.org/articles/provision-azure-boxes-with-vagrant/

but I getting this error

```
Failed to load the "vagrant-azure" plugin. View logs for more details.
```

when i run the following command

```
vagrant up --provider=azure --debug
```

The full stack trace is below. How can i verify that the vagrant plugins are correctly installed?

```
devops/vagrant/vagrant-azure$ vagrant up --provider=azure --debug
 INFO global: Vagrant version: 1.4.3
 INFO global: Ruby version: 1.9.3
 INFO global: RubyGems version: 1.8.23.2
 INFO global: VAGRANT_LOG="debug"
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/communicators/ssh/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ssh communicator
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: NFS synced folders
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: plugin command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/reload/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: reload command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/resume/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: resume command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/provision/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: provision command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/package/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: package command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/help/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: help command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/status/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: status command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/ssh_config/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ssh-config command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/suspend/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: suspend command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/up/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: up command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/destroy/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: destroy command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/box/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: box command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/halt/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: halt command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/init/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: init command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/ssh/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ssh command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/hosts/opensuse/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: OpenSUSE host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/hosts/redhat/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Red Hat host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/hosts/linux/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Linux host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/hosts/freebsd/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: FreeBSD host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/hosts/windows/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Windows host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/hosts/gentoo/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Gentoo host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/hosts/slackware/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Slackware host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/hosts/arch/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Arch host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/hosts/bsd/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: BSD host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/provisioners/file/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: file
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/provisioners/shell/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: shell
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/provisioners/salt/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: salt
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/provisioners/cfengine/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: CFEngine Provisioner
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/provisioners/docker/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: docker
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/provisioners/puppet/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: puppet
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/provisioners/chef/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: chef
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/provisioners/ansible/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ansible
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/omnios/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: OmniOS guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/suse/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: SUSE guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/pld/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: PLD Linux guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/esxi/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ESXi guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/redhat/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: RedHat guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/debian/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Debian guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/linux/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Linux guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/solaris11/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Solaris 11 guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/fedora/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Fedora guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/freebsd/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: FreeBSD guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/openbsd/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: OpenBSD guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/solaris/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Solaris guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/gentoo/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Gentoo guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/arch/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Arch guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/ubuntu/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Ubuntu guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/darwin/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Darwin guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/guests/coreos/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: CoreOS guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/providers/virtualbox/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: VirtualBox provider
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/kernel_v1/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: kernel
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/kernel_v2/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: kernel
 INFO vagrant: `vagrant` invoked: ["up", "--provider=azure", "--debug"]
DEBUG vagrant: Creating Vagrant environment
 INFO environment: Environment initialized (#<Vagrant::Environment:0x000000015ee088>)
 INFO environment:   - cwd: /home/pauloconnell/bearingpoint/devops/vagrant/vagrant-azure
 INFO environment: Home path: /home/pauloconnell/.vagrant.d
 INFO environment: Local data path: /home/pauloconnell/bearingpoint/devops/vagrant/vagrant-azure/.vagrant
DEBUG environment: Creating: /home/pauloconnell/bearingpoint/devops/vagrant/vagrant-azure/.vagrant
DEBUG environment: Loading plugins from: /home/pauloconnell/.vagrant.d/plugins.json
 INFO environment: Loading plugin from JSON: vagrant-hostsupdater
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: HostsUpdater
 INFO manager: Registered required plugin: vagrant-hostsupdater
 INFO root: Loaded plugin vagrant-hostsupdater, version 1.0.1
 INFO environment: Loading plugin from JSON: vagrant-azure
ERROR root: Failed to load plugin: vagrant-azure
ERROR root:  -- Error: #<RuntimeError: The Vagrant Azure plugin is only compatible with Vagrant 1.6+>
ERROR root:  -- Backtrace:
ERROR root: /home/pauloconnell/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-azure-1.3.0/lib/vagrant-azure/plugin.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/pauloconnell/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-azure-1.3.0/lib/vagrant-azure.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant.rb:204:in `require_plugin'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:760:in `block in load_plugins'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:751:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:751:in `load_plugins'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:132:in `initialize'
/usr/bin/vagrant:105:in `new'
/usr/bin/vagrant:105:in `<main>'
 INFO interface: error: Failed to load the "vagrant-azure" plugin. View logs for more details.

Failed to load the "vagrant-azure" plugin. View logs for more details.

 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_plugins_loaded
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x0000000169c430>
 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_load
 INFO environment: Initializing config...
 INFO loader: Set :default = "/usr/share/vagrant/config/default.rb"
DEBUG loader: Populating proc cache for "/usr/share/vagrant/config/default.rb"
DEBUG loader: Load procs for pathname: /usr/share/vagrant/config/default.rb
 INFO loader: Set :root = #<Pathname:/home/pauloconnell/bearingpoint/devops/vagrant/vagrant-azure/Vagrantfile>
DEBUG loader: Populating proc cache for #<Pathname:/home/pauloconnell/bearingpoint/devops/vagrant/vagrant-azure/Vagrantfile>
DEBUG loader: Load procs for pathname: /home/pauloconnell/bearingpoint/devops/vagrant/vagrant-azure/Vagrantfile
 INFO loader: Loading configuration in order: [:default, :home, :root]
DEBUG loader: Loading from: default (evaluating)
DEBUG loader: Loading from: root (evaluating)
DEBUG provisioner: Provisioner defined: shell
DEBUG loader: Configuration loaded successfully, finalizing and returning
DEBUG hosts: Host path search classes: [VagrantPlugins::HostOpenSUSE::Host, VagrantPlugins::HostArch::Host, VagrantPlugins::HostSlackware::Host, VagrantPlugins::HostGentoo::Host, VagrantPlugins::HostRedHat::Host, VagrantPlugins::HostFreeBSD::Host, VagrantPlugins::HostWindows::Host, VagrantPlugins::HostLinux::Host, VagrantPlugins::HostBSD::Host]
 INFO hosts: Host class: VagrantPlugins::HostLinux::Host
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x000000019743d8>
 INFO cli: CLI: [] "up" ["--provider=azure", "--"]
DEBUG cli: Invoking command class: VagrantPlugins::CommandUp::Command ["--provider=azure", "--"]
DEBUG command: 'Up' each target VM...
DEBUG command: Getting target VMs for command. Arguments:
DEBUG command:  -- names: []
DEBUG command:  -- options: {:provider=>"azure"}
DEBUG command: Loading all machines...
 INFO environment: Getting machine: default (azure)
 INFO environment: Uncached load of machine.
 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_unload
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x0000000169eb40>
ERROR vagrant: Vagrant experienced an error! Details:
ERROR vagrant: #<Vagrant::Errors::ProviderNotFound: The provider 'azure' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists.>
ERROR vagrant: The provider 'azure' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists.
ERROR vagrant: /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:321:in `machine'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:142:in `block in with_target_vms'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:175:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:175:in `block in with_target_vms'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:174:in `map'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:174:in `with_target_vms'
/usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/up/command.rb:56:in `block in execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in batch'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:208:in `tap'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:208:in `block in batch'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:207:in `batch'
/usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/up/command.rb:55:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/cli.rb:38:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:484:in `cli'
/usr/bin/vagrant:127:in `<main>'
 INFO interface: error: The provider 'azure' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists.
The provider 'azure' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: #RuntimeError: The Vagrant Azure plugin is only compatible with Vagrant 1.6+

but you have

> global: Vagrant version: 1.4.3

Upgrade vagrant to 1.6 or newer - latest version of the plugin even needs  1.7.3+